# Entity Framework not mapping parent id as foreign key in child table

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework 5.0, I want to insert rows in table which are in a parent-child relationship i.e `user` and `user_role`.

- `user` contains columns `user_id, first_names, last_name`
- `user_role` contains columns `role_id, role_name, user_id`

I've setup Entity Framework and also can see their association in designer viewer, now when I try to execute my code, constraint exception occurs which says that `user_id` is not mapped in `user_role` table

Microsoft Entity Framework  - not working:

```
using (MicrosoftEntities context = new MicrosoftEntities())
{
     USER user = new USER();
     user.FIRST_NAMES = "u";
     user.LAST_NAME = "u";

     user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10001, role_name ="a" });
     user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10002, role_name ="b" });

     context.USERZs.Add(user);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Telerik Entity Framework - working perfectly fine:

```
using (TelerikEntities context = new TelerikEntities())
{
    Telerik_USER user1 = new Telerik_USER();
    user1.FIRST_NAMES = "u";
    user1.LAST_NAME = "u";

    user1.Telerik_USER_ROLE.Add(new Telerik_USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10001 });
    user1.Telerik_USER_ROLE.Add(new Telerik_USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10002 });

    context.Add(user1);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help me out.

I am compelled to use Microsoft Entity Framework.

Entity Framework classes

```
public partial class USER
{
    public USER()
    {
        this.USER_ROLE = new HashSet<USER_ROLE>();
    }

    public long USER_ID { get; set; }
    public string FIRST_NAMES { get; set; }
    public string LAST_NAME { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<USER_ROLE> USER_ROLE { get; set; }
  }

public partial class USER_ROLE
{
    public long USER_ROLE_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> USER_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<long> ROLE_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<string> ROLE_NAME { get; set; }
    public virtual USER USER { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Do you receive any error's with EF? please show if you are.

Comment: exception says: {"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the inner exception for details."}
when i see inner exception it says: 
ORA-02291: integrity constraint (DRS.SYS_C00243194) violated - parent key not found [which is reflecting user_id in user_role table]

Comment: @tango - Can you please share the classes for `user` and `user_role` generated by the EF designer?

Comment: @ChannappaJagadish: updated my code

Answer (score 2):

The user must exist before you add the role.  You can't do it at the same time. You should do it in a transaction, but I will post working code for the inserts not the trans.

```
using (MicrosoftEntities context = new MicrosoftEntities())
{
     USER user = new USER();
     user.FIRST_NAMES = "u";
     user.LAST_NAME = "u";

     context.USERZs.Add(user);
     context.SaveChanges();


     user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10001, role_name ="a", USER_ID = user.USER_ID });
     user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10002, role_name ="b", USER_ID = user.USER_ID });
     context.SaveChanges();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your new child entities are not being tracked by EF at the time of insertion (because you `newed` them). If you used proxies and would let EF generate its own ids, it should work.

The common way of doing this is attaching the entities before `SaveChanges()`, in your case:

```
using (MicrosoftEntities context = new MicrosoftEntities())
{
     USER user = new USER();
     user.FIRST_NAMES = "u";
     user.LAST_NAME = "u";

     /** Notice we don't specify a ROLE_ID here, we let EF generate it **/
     user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { role_name ="a" });
     user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { role_name ="b" });

     /** attach all entities to the context **/
     foreach(var role in user.USER_ROLE)
     {
       context.Entry(role).State = role.ROLE_ID == default(long) ? EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
     }

     context.USERZs.Add(user);
     context.SaveChanges();
}
```

In EF7 you could use `AttachGraph`(or `TrackGraph`, not sure how it's called in final versions), in EF6 you need to do it by hand.

This could be further simplified by using proxies, creating the entities with `DbContext.Create` instead of `new`'ing them, and having a navigation property on `USER_ROLE` which is the `USER` (in case it's 0:n, which we don't know) and setting the `User` property on the role: this would take care of attaching and setting the correct ids on saving.

Sounds to me that you are moving your database issues to an ORM, and you should be abstracting from those issues. Generating your own ID's make no sense in an ORM: if things were great (which aren't, in practice), having an ORM should theoretically allow you to not care about id's at all, and use objects for relationships, not ids.

If you plan to make the work of the ORM in your code, forget about EF and ORMs and get some SQL mapper (like [Dapper.NET](https://github.com/StackExchange/dapper-dot-net) or similar), which does wonders and it's way more performant than EF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the new `User` first so you get a database generated Id (assuming it is auto generated of course):

```
using (MicrosoftEntities context = new MicrosoftEntities())
using(var transaction = context.DataBase.BeginTransaction())
{
 USER user = new USER();
 user.FIRST_NAMES = "u";
 user.LAST_NAME = "u";
 context.Users.Add(user);
 context.SaveChanges();

 user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10001, role_name ="a", userId = user.Id});
 user.USER_ROLE.Add(new USER_ROLE() { ROLE_ID = 10002, role_name ="b", userId = user.Id});

 context.SaveChanges();
 transaction.Commit();
}
```

Only works with EF6+

Comment: i need to save all respective detail in one transaction, doing so will not work in transaction

Comment: Edited answer with EF transaction

Comment: what about any sample code in EF5 ? means is this a bug in EF5 ?

Comment: It's not a bug, but this only got introduced in EF6, for earlier versions there is [TransactionScope](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb738523(v=vs.100).aspx) but never worked with that myself.

Comment: actually this is the first time i am using microsoft EF so getting problem like such else i use to work in Telerik EF and never got such an issue... i mean this is very logical to map parent child as such, how come microsoft team ignore such use case

Comment: @tango The entities are related through Id's, if you don't know the Id it's impossible to fill in the foreign key. The Telerik EF is probably doing something similar in the background

Comment: By the way, I see you updated your code. Have you mapped the relations in fluent api or did you forget to map them?

Comment: I placed code of both entities generated by MS-EF. In designer view i can see their association

Comment: No Sir, i convinced my boss over Telerik EF... i am going good now. thanks.